# What jars do I need in my project to deploy a JSF app?

Tags: xml, tomcat, jsf, web-applications

I'm at the end of my wits trying to figure this out. It's been hours.

I have a simple JSF application I created in Eclipse. I want to display a xhtml form and have a managed bean to handle it. I'm deploying this to Tomcat v8.

At firs I couldn't even get the form to display; it returns a 404 error. I finally got it to display after adding jsf-impl and jsf-api jars. But then I wanted to add core faces tags. After using those tags (added the below to the html tag)

```
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/core">
```

the page stopped displaying. So I messed around with the jars in the build path and boy was that a mistake. I removed the core faces tag references but now I am unable to get a simple page to display! You can access it here to see:

http://18.236.104.57/StuSurveyApp3/

Structure and current jars:

https://preview.ibb.co/b8mU2f/jars.png

My web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
    <display-name>StuSurveyApp3</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>

        <welcome-file>StuSurvey.xhtml</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>display.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>

    </welcome-file-list>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>

        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

I'm not even sure how to debug this. Is there a jar missing? Am I putting them in the wrong place?!

Comment: What does the Tomcat /manager tell you? Is the app deployed and started at all?

Comment: start here: https://www.stackoverflow.com/tags.jsf/info

Comment: or here: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info  @Kukeltje ;-)

Comment: sorry, typo on my phone. But a generic search in google would have helped too... please next time spend some time searching

Comment: @Kukeltje I've done many generic searches but thanks for the suggestion

Comment: [ask] states to keep track of your searches, mention those in the question mention why the do not help...